# Laravel Passport gets 'It was not possible to parse your key, reason: ""' error after upgrade to PHP8.0

Tags: php, laravel-passport, php-8

My app works on Laravel 8 with `laravel/passport 10.0.1`. After upgrading `php` version on dev server from `7.4` to `8.0`, I'm getting `It was not possible to parse your key, reason: ""` error (without any message from openssl_error_string).

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

OK, after brief investigation, I found that you have to update `laravel/passport` to `10.1.0` (the newest at the moment of posting) to make it work with `php8.0`.

Comment: Can you please include on your answer how to update? Thanks

Comment: @rhemmuuu You can run `composer require laravel/passport:~10.1.0` to install the `10.1.*` version of the package . Removing `~` before the version number will install the exact version.

Answer (score 1):

I suffered the same error this week but I resolved it by upgrading all to PHP 8.0

My composer.json

```
...
"require": {
    "php": "ˆ8.0",
}...
"config": {
   ...
   "platform": {
        "php": "Your PHP version"
   }
}
```

It's probably late for you but I hope it's useful for someone else

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error. I solved this problem via update library by composer.

```
composer update
```

to resolve this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to SO. As the previous comment suggests, "code only" Answers are accepted, but discouraged. Explanations help future visitors learn something they can apply to their own coding issues, so they tend to receive more votes over time, as coders find them to be the most helpful. Adding an explanation, and/or a link to documentation (and even a particularly useful quote from the linked page) quickens the learning curve & tends to be most appreciated by SO visitors!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error. I solved this problem via update library by composer.

composer update

Answer (score -1):

This prob means your KEYS are incorrect or the env is not finding them.

If a file you need to use the PATH

```
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY_PATH=
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY_PATH=
```