# When I login then error will be ocuurred "It was not possible to parse your key, reason". (Laravel api)

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

`{"message": "It was not possible to parse your key, reason: "}`

I also tried `composer update` command and `composer require` laravel/passport and `php artisan passport:install`.

But the same error is still occurring. Please suggest me what is the solution for this error.

Comment: welcome to so. update your question with related code and full error log. and this is possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65066495/laravel-passport-gets-it-was-not-possible-to-parse-your-key-reason-error)

Comment: sure I update my question and this duplicate question is not solution for my question if any other solution so please suggest me

Comment: Your `composer.json` file might be malformed, can you please post it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I changed the version of PHP and it's work.